# How to simulate the WatchOS on Xcode 7.0.1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, apple-watch

I recently updated my Xcode to `Version 7.0.1` and I built my first Apple Watch app.
I would like to test it but it seems like I need the actual device to be able to simulate it?
I went to `Hardware > External Devices >` and I do not see the Apple Watch option anywhere.

- Anybody else has experience this?
- What can I do to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the same simulator but another one called 'Simulator (Watch)'.
If you select the target for the Watch project, you end up with this (menu selection):

[image]

which will launch the two simulators

Answer (score 0):

Select scheme for Apple Watch in XCode and display should appear after running the project.

Answer (score 0):

My case is worse, there is even no simulator option under "Project WatchKit App" scheme.

However I am able to bring it up by adding new simulator paring with watch simulator from device management window.

1. Start any iOS simulator.
2. Go to Hardware -> Device -> Manage Devices...
3. Click the + button under the bottom left corner.

Then you will be able to add new iphone simulators paired with apple watch. Sorry, I do not have enough reputation to post image here.

Although I still can't find the watch simulator under the external displays dropdown, I can run the watch app from the "Project WatchKit App" scheme anyway.